# Any issues to expect upgrading from nginx 0.7.65 to newest version?

Tags: nginx, upgrade, legacy

I've searched this both on here and on Google with no luck, so I apologize if this has already been asked somewhere.

To give a quick background, I was tossed into a server administration role without knowing anything on account of the previous admin quitting, so for the sake of conversation let's pretend I know nothing about this, haha.

Currently our server is running nginx 0.7.65 along with Python/Django, MySQL, and so on. We've been having a lot of crashes and other issues as of late, and I'm fairly sure it's because of outdated packages. Now, with that said, we need to remember that I don't know anything about nginx.

If I run the upgrade, what kinds of possible issues can I expect? I've done some reading on updated config files and I know to use something like kdiff to merge the changes in my config file to the new one to minimize the possibility of errors, but what other issues should I be ready for?

If you need more info to give a definitive answer, then please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there shouldn't be an issue. Occasionally configuration directives change slightly, but they are simple to fix if any changes are needed. As always, test it on your development server first.